# Getting row from hyperlink in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a Hyperlink field in a asp.net gridview that runs code behind in an aspx file, like

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCoursesList" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Course" HeaderText="Course">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lblSignup" runat="server" Text="Sign Up" OnClick= "lblSignup_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In my code behind file I have the function:

```
    protected void lblSignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

How do I retrieve the value of the first column from this function.
I would like to do something like

```
string course = gvCoursesList.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

but it's not working.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jishnusaha should be the approach you should take. Here is another alternative: http://forums.asp.net/p/1137287/1821091.aspx

```
protected void lblSignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;
    GridViewRow row = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    string course = gvCoursesList.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: For me this is almost working.  I just had to change the last line to: string course = row.Cells[0].Text;  Yes, it's absolute reference, but at least it's working.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCoursesList" runat="server" OnRowCommand="gvCoursesList_RowCommand">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Course" HeaderText="Course">
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lblSignup" runat="server" Text="Sign Up" CommandName="SignUp" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

```
protected void gvCoursesList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewRowCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.CommandName=="SignUp")
  {
     string course = gvCoursesList.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  It's not quite working yet.  It complains that "The type or namespace name 'GridViewRowCommandEventArgs' could not be found"

Comment: These is not actually "GridViewCommandEventArgs"
protected void gvCoursesList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.CommandName=="SignUp")
  {
     string course = gvCoursesList.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Use the .cells.text to get the value out:

```
protected void lblSignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = gvCoursesList.rows[e.rowindex]
    string course = row.cells[cellIndex].text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - not quite working.  Get an error 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not contain a definition for 'Cells'.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but: "'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not contain a definition for 'Row'".

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to codingbiz.  His solution just needed a little tweak as per below.

```
LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;
GridViewRow row = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
string course = row.Cells[0].Text;
```